# How to open a process in C++ using popen without directing input and output to stdin?

Tags: c++, popen

I'm developing an interactive program that takes inputs from the user (through stdin) and outputs data accordingly (using stdout). While the program is running I need to open a background application (and leave it running while the main program is running). I have successfully done this using popen (using the "r" mode), however at times I get stdin conflicts. For example when the user enters an input intended for the main program, sometimes, the program treats it as an input to the background program. The user should never have to interact directly with the background program. Is there a way to completely decouple both the input and the output of the background program from stdin and stdout, while still being able to read and write using a file descriptor to the background process?

Comment: When you use `popen()` you can either read or write, not both. How are you writing to the background program?

Comment: Err, that's what `popen()` is *for*. If you don't want that, don't use it. But it seems that what you really need is `popen()` in read-write mode, so that the target process's `stdin` *is* redirected, away from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just code exactly what you need. The `popen` function is a convenience function that you can use what it happens to do exactly what you happen to need. Otherwise, use `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2`, `close`, and whatever `exec`-family function you want.

You may find it helpful to look at a few implementations of [popen/pclose](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cpTXrOJv-y8J:cnds.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/os-2011/src/popen/popen.c+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) to see how they work. Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use `popen`. Instead, use `fork` + one of the `exec` family of functions, which doesn't connect the io streams.